# Why UNION SELECT with brackets/parenthesis returns different total number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query:

```
SELECT 1, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `reg` = 3 AND `lang` = 5
UNION
SELECT 2, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `reg` = 1 AND `lang` = 2
UNION
SELECT 3, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `reg` = 6 AND `lang` = 10
```

It returns: `Showing rows 0 - 24 (435 total, Query took 0.0110 sec)`

I need to run those queries with `LIMIT 5`, so I have to use brackets around each `select` and in this case the very same query, but with brackets and limit:

```
(SELECT 1, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `reg` = 3 AND `lang` = 5 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT 2, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `reg` = 1 AND `lang` = 2 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT 3, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `reg` = 6 AND `lang` = 10 LIMIT 5)
```

returns the following: `Showing rows 0 - 24 (17098 total, 0 in query, Query took 0.0020 sec)`

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your two unions are not equivalent. The second one uses `LIMIT` in the individual selects. `UNION` removes duplicates - what happens if you use `UNION ALL` instead

Comment: No, this my type, I have just edited, sorry about that.

Comment: @A_HORSE...I tried without `limit` and with `union all`, result is unchanged: `Showing rows 0 - 24 (17098 total, 0 in query, Query took 0.0060 sec)`

Answer (score 1):

Your second query is different to the first one since in your second query you are using **LIMIT 5**

**EDIT:-**

You may try this:

```
(SELECT 1 as sort_col, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `reg` = 3 AND `lang` = 5  LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT 2, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `reg` = 1 AND `lang` = 2 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT 3, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `reg` = 6 AND `lang` = 10  LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY sort_col, `name`
```

From [MYSQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION
>   result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the
>   ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.

Comment: In your second query you are using LIMIT 5, thats why you are getting the different output. Updated my answer!

Comment: When I run the second query without `limit 5`, only with brackets, the result doesn't change: `Showing rows 0 - 49 (17098 total, 0 in query, Query took 0.0130 sec)`

Comment: Your first UNION is removing the duplicates! Have you tried using UNION ALL?

Comment: I tried without `limit` and with `union all`, result is unchanged: `Showing rows 0 - 24 (17098 total, 0 in query, Query took 0.0060 sec)`

Comment: @dmit:- [There's no need for brackets/parenthesis in a UNION statement.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653124/what-does-the-sql-standard-say-about-parentheses-in-sql-union-except-intersect-s)

Comment: I need to use `LIMIT` on each statement, so brackets are required in this case, as I've learned for docs.

Comment: I appreciate your help.... I was concerned about total number of rows it says it shows, but in both queries it returns correct set of results as expected, just different total rows as per phpmyadmin. `explain` on both queries looks absolutely the same, so I guess I'll have to leave it like that.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have not found a solution, the proposed method did not help. I don't know if this is going to be a problem in production when the table will grow to millions of rows.

Comment: @dmit:- The edit which I have done is the way in which you should do it! And that is why I have added the relevant doc in support

Comment: I've tried your method, it really did not make a difference with the result, but I really appreciate your effort, so +1

Answer (score 0):

Using brackets changes the processing of your query assigning priority of each sub query

To investigate use `Explain YOUR_QUERY` on both the queries.

Comment: Explain for both queries appears to be absolutely the same

Comment: Can you check with `order by id` in each query? Reason is UNION produces un-ordered result set [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)