# How to select data from table with different conditions in the same query

Tags: mysql

I have a table, I want selcect data from this table with condition **`type =1 , type =2, type =3`** and each type limit by 5.

If I used the following command, 3 table join to each other ); so I have 5x5x5 = 125 record!

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
  ( select * from `question` where type = 1 limit 5) as t1 , 
  (select * from `question` where type = 2 limit 5) as t2, 
  (select * from `question` where type = 3 limit 5) as t3
)
```

How can I select this data with just 1 command so I have table with 15 records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE type = 1 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE type = 2 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE type = 3 LIMIT 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use union statement

```
  (select * from question where type = 1 limit 5)
  UNION
  (select * from question where type = 2 limit 5)
  UNION
  (select * from question where type = 3 limit 5)
```

Comment: i use union but it just return a table with 5 records of type = 1?

Comment: UNION just connects the results. If you use only the second or the third query alone do you get the expected result?

Comment: @geoandri, If you used this query then it won't work as select statement should be in paranthesis. Check out my answer. It will return desired result.

Comment: No, it works perfectly without parenthesis also. Have you checked it?

Comment: yes, i have checked it. My answer was same as yours but when the OP commented on your answer, i tested it and he was right it wasn't producing correct result so i added parenthesis and it was producing desired result. So i edited my answer.

Comment: If you checked it the problem was somewhere else. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653124/what-does-the-sql-standard-say-about-parentheses-in-sql-union-except-intersect-s

Comment: @geoandri, if you check the accepted answer it clearly states that "MySQL is the only one I'm aware of at this moment, which allows you to define ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses specific to each query **as long as the query is enclosed in brackets**" that means it requires parenthesis. Also please check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html document and search for "To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, **parenthesize the individual SELECT statements** and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one." So i think we need parenthesis here.

Comment: You are right, I missed this part an my dataset when reproducing it was misleading. Thanks for your comments. I ll edit my answer.